# Php strlen() to string conversion

Tags: php

How can i return X stars (*) depending on string length using `strlen()` ?

```
<?PHP
  $account_name = "account1"; // 8 characters
  $account_name_length = strlen($account_name);

  // This is what i want to achieve - convert `$account_name` string length into stars.
  $account_name_hidden = "********"; // return 8 stars as string
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, not sure why you would want to do this, but can't you just do this?

```
<?php
$account_name = "account1" // 8 characters
$account_name_length = strlen($account_name);
$account_hidden = str_repeat('*', $account_name_length);
?>
```

Comment: That works perfect - as i expected! I'm working on a weird website for a friend. I'm not used to PHP that much. Function is basicly showing/hidding account name. Hidding it with same length of stars as the account name.

Comment: Just wondering (as I can see you didn't accept an answer to your other question), if an answer has helped you on StackOverflow, it's a courtesy to accept it (by clicking on the gray checkmark) to help others who may be facing the same problem as you and to credit the author.

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer as soon as it worked, had to wait few minutes to do that.

Comment: Oh, in that case, apologies on my part and sorry for being so presumptuous. Thanks and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$account_hidden = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $account_length; $i++) {
    $account_hidden .= '*';
}

echo $account_hidden . PHP_EOL;
```